# Internet Explorer: post data only appears on page refresh or browser back button, but not <a> tag links

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

I have a strange problem with IE.  I have a sequence of forms on my website, and there is a built in navigation system to go to the next and previous pages.  The pages submit to themselves, and then use Header(Location: ... ) to proceed to the next page.

The problem is that when I use the built in back button (standard  tags) to go to the previous page, the input tags get populated with the old values, but when I refresh the page the values are correct.  Similarly, when I use the browser back button the values appear correctly.

Sorry if this is a repost, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it just an issue with IE, or does it affect other browsers?

Comment: its only happens in IE, and works fine in chrome, FF, and safari

Comment: It sounds like it's an issue with IE caching, in that case. Can you tweak your website config so it's passing the No-cache request to the browser?

Comment: Sweet, it worked thx! If you want to submit as an answer I will accept, we used this line "Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" in .htaccess

Comment: You're welcome - I'm glad my hazy memory of caching still works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an issue with IE caching the previous pages; if you can amend the server configuration so that it's passing the No-cache request to the browser, it should fix it.